# How can I color a design in java?

Tags: java, colors, draw, background-color

Hi! I have this problem: I have to make a program in java which designs a figure of a human and I have to paint it. I have wrote the code which design the human but I dont know how to fill the shapes with color.I am aware that I have to use "java.awt.Color" but I dont know how.

The colors have to be: background of the image(yellow), head(blue), arms & legs (green), body(red).

Here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawPanelTest {
    //creates a window to display the drawing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a new frame to hold the panel
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        Container pane=application.getContentPane();
        // create a panel that contains our drawing
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        // set the frame to exit when it is closed
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        // add the panel to the frame
        pane.add(panel);
        application.setContentPane(pane);
        // set the size of the frame
        application.setSize(550, 450);
        // make the frame visible
        application.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

And here is where the figure is drawn:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        //draw the human
        g.drawOval(300, 100, 100, 100);
        g.drawRect(300, 200, 100, 100);
        g.drawRect(400,200, 100, 10);
        g.drawRect(200,200, 100, 10);
        g.drawRect(300,300, 10, 100);
        g.drawRect(390,300, 10, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know how to make it look like that.

Comment: No problem, just click the "{}" button to format a selection of your text as code

Answer (score 5):

use [g.fillOval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) in place of g.drawOval()

set the color by [g.setColor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29)

Concerning the background color, click on one link above, search for the term "background" and boom: [Graphics.clearRect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

The documentation says:

> Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I still don't know how to paint the background.Can you give me some help?                                     N

Comment: My comment was before you edited yours :P but thanks I found it out